# How to keep two div next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to keep these two `div`s side by side. I've set `50%` width for them but still they are under eachother. What's wrong?

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    two
  </div>
  <div>
    one
  </div>
</form>
```

I don't want to use `flex` display. Noted that, it would be ok if I set `49%` for the `width` property, but doesn't look standard to me. Also as you know, that `1px` border has nothing to do with the issue.

How can I keep them next to each other?
Thanks in advance

Comment: that's because margin and border also add up while calculating width of the div. better to use flexbox in this cae

Comment: Well If no restrictions I will suggest to use either bootstrap GRID or FLEXBOX to work with such things as they can adapt easily as  per the screen size and that will also avoid extra CSS for various screen sizes.

Comment: why dont u want to use `flex`?

Comment: @Anonymouse Because I don't know how `flex` works exactly .. I need to read about it and I have no free time at the momemnt..

Comment: @MartinAJ i see, its one of the most usefull thing in css so i really recommend you to learn it in ur free time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. You need to set a `box-sizing` so that the width of the element includes the border
2. You need to remove the newline between the divs since it takes an extra space

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    two
  </div><!-- you need to remove space here --><div>
    one
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I see .. great, thx

Comment: Just as a side note, my code structure looks dirty when I remove that space (new line in reality) .. Any other idea to keep the code clean?

Comment: you could set a font-size: 0 to the parent and restore it to the children, but I strongly recommend flexbox, this is a way better option.